# Чем отличается compile от implementation

Tags: android, gradle

При использовании compile появлялась ошибка о том,что лучше использовать implementation либо api.В чем разница между ними?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Данный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) есть на английской версии.

Если коротко, произошла замена методов в gradle 3.0.

`compile` на `implementation`

`testCompile` на `testImplementation`

`debugCompile` на `debugImplementation`

`androidTestCompile` на `androidTestImplementation`

Эта замена обеспечивает более быструю компиляцию.